# Nested class with Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm developing my own framework on Swift and I'm using Core Data. Until now everything was working fine until I decide to add a new class as nested class. So I configure an entity called Info and set its class to MyFramework.MyClass.MyInfoClass. However this case looks that it is not being accepted.

```
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'MyFramework.MyClass.MyInfoClass' for entity 'Info'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
```

Does anyone know if there is a restriction for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@objc(MyClass)
class MyClass: NSManagedObject {

    ...

}
```